# Render picture module image in a custom module

Tags: media

I am trying to render a responsive picture module image from within a module. I cant find any functions that I can pass the picture mapping into.
If I render the whole node from within the module it works fine but if I just render the image it does not work.
Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding 'default' to the functions arguments sorted it out

```
$field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image', 'default');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to build the render array of the drupal 7 picture module v2

```
//Load picture renderable array

$picture_name = 'mapping_name'
$fallback_image_style = 'large';

$image = $node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0];

$picture_mappings = picture_mapping_load($picture_name);

$breakpoint_styles = picture_get_mapping_breakpoints($picture_mappings, $fallback_image_style);

$picture = array(
        '#theme' => 'picture',
        '#width' => isset($image['width']) ? $image['width'] : NULL,
        '#height' => isset($image['height']) ? $image['height'] : NULL,
        '#style_name' => $fallback_image_style,
        '#breakpoints' => $breakpoint_styles,
        '#uri' => $image['uri'],
        '#alt' => isset($image['alt']) ? $image['alt'] : '',
        '#attributes' => isset($image['attributes']) ? $image['attributes'] : NULL,
        '#timestamp' => $image['timestamp'],
      );

print render($picture);
```

Comment: Note the `$image` value if you only have a system path you can use `image_get_info('public:image/in/files.png')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [field_view_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) function.
eg.

```
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_name');
```

read more about the correct way to render node fields at [this blog post](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way)

Comment: I have tried this but it does not give the Picture module responsive version of the image, just the original.